# How to interleave 2 booleans using bitwise operators?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

Suppose I have two 4-bit values, `ABCD` and `abcd`. How to interleave it, so it becomes `AaBbCcDd`, using bitwise operators? Example in pseudo-C:

```
nibble a = 0b1001;
nibble b = 0b1100;
char c = foo(a,b);
print_bits(c); 
// output: 0b11010010
```

Note: 4 bits is just for illustration, I want to do this with two 32bit ints.

Comment: But two 32 bit integers will result in 64 bits if we concatenate them in ur fashion but `nibble c` can hold only 32 bits. Right?

Comment: Sorry, updated (I want to make a 64 bit int).

Comment: I think `interleave` may be a better word than `mix`

Comment: Indeed it is, updated.

Comment: Why are you saying "booleans" (i.e. 1-bit values) in your title, but talking about 4-bit and 32-bit values in your question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is called the *perfect shuffle* operation, and it's discussed at length in the Bible Of Bit Bashing, [Hacker's Delight](http://www.hackersdelight.org/) by Henry Warren, section 7-2 "Shuffling Bits."

Assuming `x` is a 32-bit integer with `a` in its high-order 16 bits and `b` in its low-order 16 bits:

```
   unsigned int x = (a << 16) | b;   /* put a and b in place */
```

the following straightforward C-like code accomplishes the perfect shuffle:

```
x = (x & 0x0000FF00) << 8 | (x >> 8) & 0x0000FF00 | x & 0xFF0000FF;
x = (x & 0x00F000F0) << 4 | (x >> 4) & 0x00F000F0 | x & 0xF00FF00F;
x = (x & 0x0C0C0C0C) << 2 | (x >> 2) & 0x0C0C0C0C | x & 0xC3C3C3C3;
x = (x & 0x22222222) << 1 | (x >> 1) & 0x22222222 | x & 0x99999999;
```

He also gives an alternative form which is faster on some CPUs, and (I think) a little more clear and extensible:

```
unsigned int t;  /* an intermediate, temporary variable */
t = (x ^ (x >> 8)) & 0x0000FF00;  x = x ^ t ^ (t << 8);
t = (x ^ (x >> 4)) & 0x00F000F0;  x = x ^ t ^ (t << 4);
t = (x ^ (x >> 2)) & 0x0C0C0C0C;  x = x ^ t ^ (t << 2);
t = (x ^ (x >> 1)) & 0x22222222;  x = x ^ t ^ (t << 1);
```

I see you have edited your question to ask for a 64-bit result from two 32-bit inputs.  I'd have to think about how to extend Warren's technique.  I think it wouldn't be too hard, but I'd have to give it some thought.  If someone else wanted to start here and give a 64-bit version, I'd be happy to upvote them.

**EDITED FOR 64 BITS**

I extended the second solution to 64 bits in a straightforward way.  First I doubled the length of each of the constants.  Then I added a line at the beginning to swap adjacent *double-bytes* and intermix them.  In the following 4 lines, which are pretty much the same as the 32-bit version, the first line swaps adjacent *bytes* and intermixes, the second line drops down to nibbles, the third line to double-bits, and the last line to single bits.

```
unsigned long long int t;  /* an intermediate, temporary variable */
t = (x ^ (x >> 16)) & 0x00000000FFFF0000ull;  x = x ^ t ^ (t << 16);
t = (x ^ (x >> 8))  & 0x0000FF000000FF00ull;  x = x ^ t ^ (t << 8);
t = (x ^ (x >> 4))  & 0x00F000F000F000F0ull;  x = x ^ t ^ (t << 4);
t = (x ^ (x >> 2))  & 0x0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0Cull;  x = x ^ t ^ (t << 2);
t = (x ^ (x >> 1))  & 0x2222222222222222ull;  x = x ^ t ^ (t << 1);
```

Comment: Interesting, but it still doesn't look obvious enough to me - some magic hexs there. How could I extend it so that `x` is actually 64 bits and `a` and `b` are 32 bits?

Comment: Does that edit help?  It's just an extension of the same pattern to a word size that's twice as long.

Comment: Well I just, right now, managed to decode it and do it myself! Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

From Stanford "Bit Twiddling Hacks" page:
 https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#InterleaveTableObvious

```
 uint32_t x = /*...*/, y = /*...*/;
 uint64_t z = 0;

 for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(x) * CHAR_BIT; i++) // unroll for more speed...
 {
     z |= (x & 1U << i) << i | (y & 1U << i) << (i + 1);
 }
```

Look at the page they propose different and faster algorithms to achieve the same.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a loop-based solution that is hopefully more readable than some of the others already here.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


uint64_t interleave(uint32_t a, uint32_t b) {
    uint64_t result = 0;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 31; i++) {
        result |= (a >> (31 - i)) & 1;
        result <<= 1;
        result |= (b >> (31 - i)) & 1;
        result <<= 1;
    }

    // Skip the last left shift.
    result |= (a >> (31 - i)) & 1;
    result <<= 1;
    result |= (b >> (31 - i)) & 1;
    return result;
}
void printBits(uint64_t a) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 64; i++)
        printf("%lu", (a >> (63 - i)) & 1);
    puts("");
}
int main(){
    uint32_t a = 0x9;
    uint32_t b = 0x6;
    uint64_t c = interleave(a,b);
    printBits(a);
    printBits(b);
    printBits(c);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like so:

```
#include <limits.h>

typedef unsigned int       half;
typedef unsigned long long full;

full mix_bits(half a,half b)
{
    full result = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<sizeof(half)*CHAR_BIT; i++)
        result |= (((a>>i)&1)<<(2*i+1))|(((b>>i)&1)<<(2*i+0));
    return result;
}
```

Comment: But it should receive a 32bit int and return a log... that is returning just a int, right? So I don't get it...!

Comment: @Viclib: Sorry, just noticed you mentioned 4-bit values as an example.

Answer (score 1):

I have used the 2 tricks/operations used in this post [How do you set, clear, and toggle a single bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981/how-do-you-set-clear-and-toggle-a-single-bit-in-c-c) of `setting a bit at particular index` and `checking the bit at particular index`.

The following code is implemented using these 2 operations only.

```
int a = 0b1001;
int b = 0b1100;
long int c=0;
int index;   //To specify index of c
int bit,i;

//Set bits in c from right to left.
for(i=32;i>=0;i--)
{
    index=2*i+1;   //We have to add the bit in c at this index

    //Check a

    bit=a&(1<<i);  //Checking whether the i-th bit is set in a
    if(bit)
      c|=1<<index; //Setting bit in c at index

    index--;

    //Check b

    bit=b&(1<<i);  //Checking whether the i-th bit is set in b
    if(bit)
      c|=1<<index; //Setting bit in c at index
}
printf("%ld",c);
```

Output: `210` which is `0b11010010`